# How to embed existing react app to WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I'm trying to embed an existing react app to my WordPress site using the plugin ReactPress. I created a react app inside the plugin section:

[image]

and added my build folder of the existing react app inside the path where is needed (using file administrator plugin):

[image]

The Path is wp-content/plugins/reactpress/apps/dase-mural-design. The problem is when I click on the URL Slug in order to see this section (where the build folder is placed) I don't see the react app I've just uploaded, I just see header and footer and these errors:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I used FileZilla to upload these files but is still not showing anything. Any idea?

[image]

I changed the package.json homepage to: "homepage": "/wp-content/plugins/reactpress/apps/dase-mural-design/build",

But in the console of the WordPress site I see:
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's an encoding [issue](https://github.com/TronLink/tronlink-extension/issues/248), try [setting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/special-characters-in-wordpress-utf-8) your site encoding to utf-8 or uploading the files of your react app with a [different tool](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-filezilla/), it could be the file manager plugin is changing the encoding when uploading.

Comment: how can I change my site encoding to utf-8? @diedu

Comment: Find this line on wp-config.php 
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' ); & change as per your needs

Comment: I used filezilla to upload the build files but is still not working. Any idea? @ShaikhAejazAhmed

Comment: Did you changed site encoding as @diedu said ? You marked the answer so i thought issue is resolved

Comment: I did not change the encoding, I just uploaded the files using FileZilla. The issue is not resolved because the page is still not appearing. I updated the question. Do you have any idea about what is happening?

Comment: @Xim123 please try changing the encoding as indicated here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/special-characters-in-wordpress-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I was able to have the React application display by adding an HTML block containing a div with the ID "root".

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

See this other post: [embeddable widget using React.js uncaught error minified react error #299](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75734096/embeddable-widget-using-react-js-uncaught-error-minified-react-error-299)