# embeddable widget using React.js uncaught error minified react error #299

Tags: reactjs, parcel

I am going to build an embeddable widget using React.js library.
I built the widget using the command "parcel build src/index.js --no-source-maps -d widget" successfully.
But when running the js and css files which are built in any website, I have encountered an error "Uncaught Error: Minified React error #299".
I researched many blogs, but I haven't found the solution.
Please let me know the solution if you have experience.

[image]

Comment: Did you visit the https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=299 page from the error message? That gives the full error text, which should help you track down the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same error with my React app - a similar embeddable widget app as well. The way I fixed it was when I added the widget to a webpage, I had to add a div with the "root" id - the error comes from not being able to create a root for the app so by explicitly adding a root div then the app rendered properly.

Something like this:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="path-to-script.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You saved me, I copied similar code but your explanation made me realize that the div's id and the script's id should be the same.